# Drawing dot in OneNote does not coincide with it's trace while using pen

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop, microsoft-onenote, pen, bamboo

While in draw mode, a mouse cursor turns to dot, which remain trace while drawing. It can be drawn both with mouse and pen. While drawing with pen, a trace appears slightly righter than a dot. This is not the case while drawing with mouse.

Drawing in other applications like Photoshop, doesn't show this behavior.

Pen is Wacom Bamboo Pen. OS is Windows 8.

Comment: Are there any calibration options in driver's settings?

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I have the same problem. I have a bamboo pen and touch, it works fine in all other applications, only OneNote seems to have this problem: drawing short lines when I'm trying to draw dots close to each other - like dotting an 'i' or when crossing a 't'. Also, this only happens when drawing with the pen, mouse operation works fine.
*[win7, office 2010]*

Found the **SOLUTION**! (just as I was getting ready to post only the above text)
Goto Bamboo Dock > Bamboo Settings > My Tablet *[TAB]* > Pen Tablet Properties *[BUTTON]* > Pen *[TAB]*. Then **decrease the Double Click Distance** *[slider]*.